# Multi step large form validations

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, validation

Add validation in each fields of a every multi step of a form the next tab and the upper(header tab) will be enable when only all the fields are valid and filled. Submit button should be in last step which will enable when all the fields of last steps are fill with file uploads filed.

In first step I am trying to validate email with organisation input, means when email is correct then only next will enable. and in next step select options tag validation is not working i tried with javascript . after this i have to insert this all fields into two database table using php and mysql, that i will do later; please find full code.

```
<?php include("../../conn.php"); ?>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.3/jquery.min.js"></script>





<!DOCTYPE html>
  <html lang="en">
    <head>
      <meta charset="UTF-8">
  

      <base href="../../">
 
        <!-- Navbar -->
 
        <meta charset="UTF-8">

        <!-- Fonts -->
        <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
        <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=DM+Sans:ital,wght@0,400;0,700;1,400;1,700&family=Montserrat:ital,wght@0,300;0,400;0,600;0,700;1,300;1,400;1,600;1,700&family=Roboto:ital,wght@0,300;0,400;0,700;1,300;1,400;1,700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">

        <!-- DataTables CSS-->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/5.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.13.2/css/dataTables.bootstrap5.min.css"/>


        <!-- Bootstrap Icons -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-icons@1.10.3/font/bootstrap-icons.css">

        <!-- Font Awesome v6 JS -->
        <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/64b7be69f4.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

        <!-- Additional CSS -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/custom.css">
    </head>
    


  <body>

    <script src="assets/js/initTheme.js"></script>
    <div class="container-fluid pt-4 mt-3">
      <div class="row">

        <main class="col-md-9 ms-sm-auto col-xl-10 px-md-4 bg-secondary-subtle">
          <div id="app">

            <div id="main">
              <div class="page-content">
                <div class="container">
                  <div class=" text-center mt-5 ">
                    <h1>Submit your information</h1>
                  </div>

                      <div class="main_div">
                        <div class="buttons">
                          <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-lg-3 mx-auto ">
                              <button  id="submit_info" class="btn btn-primary">
                                <a href="dashboard/submit/lol.php#" onclick="divVisibility('Div1');" style= "color:white">User Information</a>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-lg-3 mx-auto ">
                              <button  id="submit_info" class="btn btn-primary enableOnInput" onclick="divVisibility('Div2');" disabled>
                                <a href="dashboard/submit/lol.php#" style= "color:white">Study Details</a>
                              </button>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-lg-3 mx-auto">
                              <button  id="submit_info" class="btn btn-primary enableOnstudyInput" onclick="divVisibility('Div3');" disabled>
                                <a href="dashboard/submit/lol.php#"  style= "color:white">Sample Details</a>
                              </button>
                            </div>

                          </div> 
                        </div>

                        <div class="inner_div">
                          <div id="Div1">
                            <form id="add_form_detail" role="form" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']); ?>" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data"> 
                              <div class="controls">
                                
                                <h4>User  Information:</h4>
                                <div class="row">

                                  <div class="col-md-6">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                      <label for="form_oganization">Organization *</label>
                                      <input id="org"  name="organization" class="form-control" placeholder="Please enter your Organization *" data-error="Valid Organization is required." autocomplete="off">
                                    <!-- <span class="error" style ="color:red"> <?//= $organizationErr; ?></span> -->
                                    </div>
                                  </div>
        
                                  <div class="col-md-6">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                      <label for="form_email">Email *</label>
                                      <input id="studyemail" type="email" name="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Please enter your email *" data-error="Valid email is required." autocomplete="off">   
                                    <!--  <span class="error" style ="color:red"> <?//= $emailErr; ?></span> -->
                                    </div>
                                  </div>

                                  <div class="col-md-12">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                      <label for="form_message">Message *</label>
                                      <textarea id="form_message" name="message" class="form-control " placeholder="Write your Study description here." rows="4" data-error="Please, leave us a message."></textarea>
                                    </div>
                                  </div>

                                </div>
                                <div class=" text-center">
                                  <button  type="submit" name="submit" id="submit_info" class="btn btn-primary enableOnInput" onclick="divVisibility('Div2');" disabled>
                                    <a href="dashboard/submit/lol.php#" style= "color:white">Next</a>
                                  </button>
                                </div>
                              </div>
                            </form>
                          </div>
                        
                          <div id="Div2" style="display: none;">
                                <!-- study form -->
                            <form id="add_form_detail" role="form" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']); ?>" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data"> 
                              <div class="controls">
                                
                                <h4>Study Details:</h4>
                                  <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-md-4">
                                      <div class="form-group">
                                        <label for="form_need">Data Type *</label>
                                        <select id ="selectdt" name="ge_me"  class="form-select" aria-label="Default select example" data-error="Please specify your need.">
                                          <option selected disabled>--Select Your Datatype--</option>
                                          <option>Genome</option>
                                          <option> Metagenome</option>
                                        </select>
                                      </div>
                                    </div>
                  
                                    <div class="col-md-4">
                                      <div class="form-group">
                                        <label for="form_sequencing platform ">Sequencing Platform *</label>
                                        <input id="seqpl" type="sequencing platform" name="sequencing_platform" class="form-control" placeholder="Please enter your Sequencing Platform *" data-error="Valid Sequencing_Platformis required.">
                                       
                                      </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-md-4">
                                      <div class="form-group">
                                        <label for="form_sequenced_region">Sequenced region *</label>
                                        <input id="seqreg" type="Sequenced_region" name="Sequenced_region" class="form-control" placeholder="Please enter your Sequenced region *" data-error="Valid Sequenced region  is required.">
                                      </div>
                                    </div>
                                
                                    <div class="col-md-4">
                                      <div class="form-group">
                                        <?php
                                        echo "<label for='form_lastname'>Environment *</label>;
                                        <select id='studyenv' name='study_env' class='form-select' aria-label='Default select example'  data-error='Please specify your need. required'>
                                          <option value='' selected disabled>--Select Environment--</option>";
                                          
                                            $query = "SELECT main_environment FROM main_environments";
                                            $result = mysqli_query($conn,$query);
                                            while($rows = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
                                          ?>

                                          <option><?php echo $rows ["main_environment"]; ?></option>
                                          <?php 
                                            } 
                                          ?> 
                                        </select>
                                     
                                      </div>
                                    </div>
                                
                                
                                    <div class="col-md-4">
                                      <div class="form-group">
                                        <label for="form_need">State *</label>
                                        <select id="studystate" name="state" class="form-select" aria-label="Default select example" data-error="Please specify your need. required">
                                          <option >--Select State--</option>
                                          <?php
                                            $query = "SELECT state_name FROM states";
                                            $result = mysqli_query($conn,$query);
                                            while($rows = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
                                          ?>

                                          <option><?php echo $rows ["state_name"]; ?></option>
                                          <?php 
                                            } 
                                          ?> 
                                        </select> 
                                        
                                      </div>
                                    </div>
                                  
                                  </div>

                                </div>
                                <div class=" text-center">
                                 
                                  <button  id="submit_info" class="btn btn-primary enableOnstudyInput" onclick="divVisibility('Div3');" disabled>
                                    <a href="dashboard/submit/lol.php#" style= "color:white">Next</a>
                                  </button>
                                </div>
                              </div>
                            </form>
                          </div>
                          <div id="Div3" style="display: none;">
                            <form id="add_form_detail" role="form" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']); ?>" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data"> 
                              <div class="controls">
                                
                                <h4>Sample Details:</h4>
                                  <div class="row">
                                  
                                    <div class="col-md-4">
                                      <div class="form-group">
                                        <label for="form_need">Data Type *</label>
                                        <select id ="selectdt" name="ge_me"  class="form-select" aria-label="Default select example" data-error="Please specify your need.">
                                          <option selected disabled>--Select Your Datatype--</option>
                                          <option>Genome</option>
                                          <option> Metagenome</option>
                                        </select>
                                      </div>
                                    </div>

                                    <div class='col-md-3'>
                                      <div class="form-group">
                                        <label class='inline'>No. of Sample *
                                          <input  id ="studysample" name="sample_size" type='number' data-id='textInput' min="1" max="1500" required />
                                        </label>
                                      </div>
                                    </div>
                        
                             
                                      <div class='col-md-4 my-4'>
                                      <div class='form-group'>
                                        <label>Library Type *</label>
                                        
                                        <div class='col-md-4'>
                                          <label>Single end: <input type='radio' data-id='single' name='check' value="singl-end" disabled /></label>
                                          <label>Paired end: <input type='radio' data-id='pair' name='check' value="pair-end" disabled /></label>
                                        </div>
                                      </div>
                                    </div>
                                  
                              </div>
                              <div class=" text-center">
                                
                                  <p required="required" >
                                    <input id ="opensample" class="btn btn-link" type='button' data-id='add' value='Click to add samples' onclick="divVisibility('Div4');" disabled  />
                                  </p>
                                </div>
                            
                              
                              </div>
                            </form>
                          </div>
                          <div id="Div4" style="display: none;">
                            <form id="add_form_detail" role="form" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']); ?>" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data"> 
                              <div class="controls">
                                
                                <h4>Add Sample Details:</h4>
                                <div id="divDynamicTexts">
                             
                                  <div class="col-md-12 text-center">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                      <button onclick="submit()" type="submit" id="submit_newdata" class="btn btn-primary enableOnInput" name="submit" disabled>Submit</button>
                                    </div>
                                  </div>
                                </div>
                              </div>
                            </form>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                      </div>

                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          
          </div>
        
        </main>
      </div>
    </div>
```

```
<script>

const strhtml =     `<div data-id="dynrow" class="row border-top py-3">
                      <div class="col-md-3">
                        <div class="form-group">
                          <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-6"> 
                              <label for="form_latitude">Latitude *</label>
                              <input id="reqlat" type="latitude" name="lat[]" class="form-control" placeholder="Please enter latitude *" >
                             
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-6"> 
                              <label for="form_longitude">Longitude *</label>
                              <input id="form_long" type="longitude" name="long[]" class="form-control" placeholder="Please eter longitude *"  >
                              
                            </div>
                           </div>
                        </div>
                       </div>  
                      <div class="col-md-3">
                        <div class="form-group">
                          <label for="form_lastname">Environment *</label>
                          <select name="sampleEnv[]" class="form-select"  aria-label="Default select example">
                            <option value="" selected disabled>--Select Environment--</option>
                            <?php
                              $query = "SELECT env_name FROM environments";
                              $result = mysqli_query($conn,$query);
                              while($rows = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
                            ?>

                            <option><?php echo $rows ["env_name"]; ?></option>
                            <?php 
                              } 
                            ?> 
                          </select>
                        </div>
                      </div>      
                       <div class="col-md-3">
                         <div class="form-group">
                           <label for="form_source">Isolation Source *</label>
                           <input id="form_source" type="source" name="source[]"  class="form-control" placeholder="Please enter your source *">
                         </div>
                       </div>
                       <div class="col-md-3">
                         <div class="form-group">
                          <label for="form_cdate">Collection Date *</label>
                          <input id="form_cdate" type="cdate" name="cdate[]"  class="date-picker form-control" placeholder="Please enter your cdate *">
                         </div>
                       </div>
                      <div class="col-md-3" style="display:none" data-id="single" data-role="file-field">
                        <div class="form-group">
                          <label>Upload file *<input type="file"  name="single_file[1]" /></label>                   
                        </div>
                      </div>
                      <div class="col-md-3" style="display:none" data-id="pair" data-role="file-field">
                        <div class="form-group ">
                          <label>Upload Forward file *<input type="file"  name="forward_file[1]" /></label>
                          <label>Upload Reverse file *<input type="file"  name="reverse_file[2]" /></label>        
                        </div>
                      </div>
                         
                      </div>
                  </div>`;




const _radio = document.querySelectorAll('[type="radio"][data-id]');
const _bttn = document.querySelector('[type="button"][data-id="add"]');
const _div = document.querySelector('#divDynamicTexts');
const _input = document.querySelector('input[type="number"][data-id="textInput"]');

let choice = false;
let qty = false;


_input.addEventListener('change', e => {
  _radio.forEach(n => {
    n.disabled = e.target.value > 0 ? false : true;
  });
  qty=e.target.value;
});



document.addEventListener('click', e => {
  if (e.target instanceof HTMLInputElement && e.target.dataset.id != null) {

    if (e.target.type == 'radio') {
      choice = e.target.dataset.id;
      _bttn.disabled = false;
    }
  }
  

  if (choice && qty > 0 && e.target.type == 'button') {
    _div.innerHTML = '';
    for (let i = 0; i < qty; i++) _div.insertAdjacentHTML('afterbegin', strhtml);

    let expr = `div[data-id="${choice}"]`;
    document.querySelectorAll(expr).forEach(n => n.style.display = 'block');
  }


  if (e.target instanceof HTMLButtonElement && e.target.dataset.id != null) {
    if (e.target.dataset.id == 'remove') {
      _div.removeChild(e.target.closest('[data-id="dynrow"]'));
    }
  }
});
                  


var divs = ["Div1", "Div2", "Div3", "Div4"];
    var visibleDivId = null;
    function divVisibility(divId) {
      if(visibleDivId === divId) {
        visibleDivId = null;
      } else {
        visibleDivId = divId;
      }
      hideNonVisibleDivs();
    }
    function hideNonVisibleDivs() {
      var i, divId, div;
      for(i = 0; i < divs.length; i++) {
        divId = divs[i];
        div = document.getElementById(divId);
        if(visibleDivId === divId) {
          div.style.display = "block";
        } else {
          div.style.display = "none";
        }
      }
    }

 //enable Study detail button
    
 $(function() {
      $('#org, #studyemail, #usrmsg').on('keyup change',
      
      function() {
        if ($('#org').val() == '' || $('#studyemail').val() == '' || $('#usrmsg').val() == '')

    {
          $('.enableOnInput').prop('disabled', true);

        }
 
        else {

          $('.enableOnInput').prop('disabled', false);
        }
      });
    });
 
    //enable sample detail button

    $(function() {
      $('#selectdt, #seqpl, #seqreg, #studyenv, #studystate').on('keyup change',
      
      function() {
        if ($('#selectdt').val() == '' || $('#seqpl').val() == '' || $('#seqreg').val() == '' || $('#studyenv').val() == '' || $('#studystate').val() == '') {
        
        $('.enableOnstudyInput').prop('disabled', true);

        }

        
        else {

          $('.enableOnstudyInput').prop('disabled', false);
        }
      }
      );
    });





// Example starter JavaScript for disabling form submissions if there are invalid fields
var form = document.getElementById('bootstrap-form')
form.addEventListener('submit', function (event){

    // add was-validated to display custom colors
    form.classList.add('was-validated')

    if (!form.checkValidity()) {
        event.preventDefault()
        event.stopPropagation()
    }
}, false)
</script>
```

Comment: You have `<a>` tags inside `<button>` tags. That is invalid and doesn't make sense.

Comment: I think that is not a issue

Comment: I wouldn't let it through a Code Review.

Comment: There is too much code with too many things that need to be fixed. You will have to reduce the scope of your issue in order to reasonably expect others to help. Here is an example to help get you started: https://jsfiddle.net/76484/za36dm01/